# PHP Curl connection to Amazon MWS Seller API

Tags: php, ssl, curl, amazon-mws

I am trying to send a request via PHP's Curl library to the Amazon seller API's ListOrders function. I am able to connect, but I am getting an AccessDenied error from their service. The documentation says that this means I am trying to connect without HTTPS, but the url I am connecting to is https://mws.amazonservices.com/

Here is my curl request

```
private function send_request()
{
        $string = '';
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($this->options as $k => $v)
            {
            $string .= rawurlencode($k) . "=" . rawurlencode($v);
            $string .= ($count == count($this->options) -1)? '': "&";
            $count++;
            }
        $options = array(
                CURLOPT_CAINFO=> <<Cert location>>,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
                CURLOPT_POST=>true,
                CURLOPT_PORT=>443,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> $string,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>2,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> TRUE,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
                CURLOPT_HEADER=>true,
                CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=> CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
                CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>true
        );
        $session = curl_init($this->url);
        curl_setopt_array($session, $options);
        $results = curl_exec($session);
        $errors = curl_error($session);
        $info = curl_getinfo($session);
        curl_close($session);
        echo htmlentities($results);//var_dump($errors);
        echo "<br /><br />";
        print_r($info);
        return $results;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01">
 <Error> 
    <Type>Sender</Type> 
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code> 
    <Message>Access to Orders.ListOrders is denied</Message> 
</Error> 
<RequestID>4e60baef-b2a4-44aa-a18f-dd6fe8b07cf5</RequestID> </ErrorResponse>
```

and my curl info printout is:

```
        Array
(
    [url] => https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2012-11-27
    [content_type] => text/xml
    [http_code] => 401
    [header_size] => 362
    [request_size] => 494
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.42
    [namelookup_time] => 0.016
    [connect_time] => 0.078
    [pretransfer_time] => 1.342
    [size_upload] => 345
    [size_download] => 310
    [speed_download] => 218
    [speed_upload] => 242
    [download_content_length] => 310
    [upload_content_length] => 345
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.42
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
```

My data is formatted correctly for the request (signature is valid, etc). Is this problem the result of me making this request from a non-SSL protected site (even though I am connecting to their https site), or is there something else I am missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: WHich port you are using for connection ? *CURLOPT_PORT* should be 433

Comment: When I switch to Port 433, I get a curl_error f= Couldn't connect to host. I took the port 443 thing from their php library curl submission.

Comment: sorry it should be 443 not 433 . 443 worked ?

Comment: 443 gives me the "AccessDenied" error from Amazon MWS

Answer (score 2):

The access was denied due to an error in the tag for an element. Amazon documentation states that you can use either Merchant or SellerId, I was using Merchant, and needed SellerId. The script above properly sends the request to Amazon.